# Is there any way to query for current touches in the Android NDK or Java API?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-ndk

The canonical way to get touch events in Android is to override the onTouchEvent of the Activity. My question is: is there a way to query or poll for all current touches? Either in the NDK API or Java API? My research suggests the answer is no, but I'm new to Android and want to confirm this is the case, as it seems surprising to me.

(Why? I need to get additional touch information from the API from within a program created using the Unity3D game engine. Unity provides a relatively simple ways to call Android's Java API and access NDK calls. If I could just ask Android "give me the current touch info" on demand from either Java or at the NDK level, that would make things straightforward. If there's no way, I have to implement a way to hook into the event loop, which is more complicated to integrate with Unity and something I'd like to avoid if possible.)

Comment: Just curious, in what would this be different from overriding onTouchEvent? What additional feature are you looking for?

Comment: @mvai -- I need to get additional touch information from the API from within a Unity3D program. Unity provides a relatively simple ways to call Android's Java API and also to access NDK calls. If I could just ask Android "give me the current touch info" on demand, that would make things straightforward. If there's no way, I have to implement a way to hook into the event loop, which is more complicated. (Thanks for asking -- I've put motivation into the main question.)

Comment: I see. For what it's worth, I believe you are right saying there's no such API.